# Необъяснимое несрабатывание функции

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет.
Делаю простой слайдер. Слайд, по бокам кнопки, при нажатии на кнопки переключаем на предыдущий или на следующий слайд. Ходит по кругу.
Разумеется к кнопкам привязаны функции (nextSlide, prevSlide), которые по нажатию на иконку, меняют индекс записанный в state, в результате отображается следующий или предыдущий слайд.
С нажатием на иконки мышкой все прекрасно работает.

Захотел чтобы еще и с клавиатуры срабатывало. Вешаю слушатель на window и по событию keydown вызываю функцию, которая вызывает nextSlide (нажатие на стрелку вправо или пробел) или prevSlide (нажатие на стрелку влево). И здесь наблюдается странный глюк. Все корректно срабатывает при первом вызове функции prevSlide или nextSlide по нажатию кнопки на клавиатуре. Если повторно вызывается та же функция, она вызывается (срабатывает console.log), но по необъяснимой причине не изменяет стэйт, соответственно слайд также не меняется.

Почему? Что не так?

````
import { FaArrowAltCircleRight, FaArrowAltCircleLeft } from 'react-icons/fa';

export const Carousel = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current', current)
  }, [current])

  const nextSlide = () => {
    console.log('nextSlide')
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
  }

  const prevSlide = () => {
    console.log('prevSlide')
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1)
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log('handleKeyDown', e.code)
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'Space': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowRight': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowLeft': {
        prevSlide();
        break;
      }

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className='slider'>
      <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className='left-arrow' onClick={prevSlide} />
      {
        slides.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'} key={index}>
              {index === current && (
                <img src={slide} alt='travel' className='image' />
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
      <FaArrowAltCircleRight className='right-arrow' onClick={nextSlide} />
    </section>
  )
} ```
````

Comment: именно из-за таких проблем не рекомендуется внутри useEffect использовать функции объявленные вне его.

Answer (score 1):

> по необъяснимой причине не изменяет стэйт, соответственно слайд также не меняется

Причина сводится к тому что функция назначенная в `useEffect` без зависимостей не видит измененную переменную стейта. Для нее она всегда одна и та же.

Предложу пару вариантов решения проблемы

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React

const Carousel = _ => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = 10;


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current', current)
  }, [current])

  const nextSlide = () => {
    console.log('nextSlide')
    setCurrent(old => old === length - 1 ? 0 : old + 1)
  }

  const prevSlide = () => {
    console.log('prevSlide')
    setCurrent(old => old === 0 ? length - 1 : old - 1)
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log('handleKeyDown', e.code)
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'Space': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowRight': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowLeft': {
        prevSlide();
        break;
      }

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  useEffect(_ => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return _ => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <section className='slider'>
      <button onClick={prevSlide}>Уменьшить</button>
      <p>{current}</p>
      <button onClick={nextSlide}>Увеличить</button>
    </section>
  )
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<Carousel />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  
<div id='root'></div>
```

Так же еще можно и вот так сделать

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React

const Carousel = _ => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = 10;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    console.log('nextSlide')
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1)
  }

  const prevSlide = () => {
    console.log('prevSlide')
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1)
  }

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log('handleKeyDown', e.code)
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'Space': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowRight': {
        nextSlide();
        break;
      }

      case 'ArrowLeft': {
        prevSlide();
        break;
      }

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  useEffect(_ => {
    console.log('current', current)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return _ => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    }
  }, [current])
  
  
  return (
    <section className='slider'>
      <button onClick={prevSlide}>Уменьшить</button>
      <p>{current}</p>
      <button onClick={nextSlide}>Увеличить</button>
    </section>
  )
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<Carousel />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Предварительно разобрался. Функция которая вешается на слушатель событий замыкается, т.е. она будет всегда видеть то значение state, которое было в момент когда мы повесили ее на слушатель.
Поэтому когда значение state меняется, функцию нужно освежить. Убрать и повесить новый экземпляр. Это легко достигается добавление стэйта в зависимости.
`  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    }
  }, [current])`

Comment: ты хоть как-то описывай что именно поменялось

Comment: @Vasily, мой первый вариант (функция, обновляющая стейт) предпочтительнее "освежения" функций.

Comment: @Grundy, массив зависимостей был [], а стал [current]

Comment: @ksa, интересный вариант. Спасибо.
Почему ты говоришь что такой вариант предпочтительнее?

Comment: @Vasily, оба варианта не очень, потому что в них тяжело сказать что от чего зависит в useEffect

Comment: @Vasily, в первом варианте не нужно "обновлять" функции. CB-функция стейта примет старый стейт и вернет новый в любом случае.

Comment: @Grundy, покажи свои варианты, которые будут "очень" и в которых будет легко сказать про зависимости в `useEffect`.

Comment: @ksa, спасибо, понял.